# Select only 1 row if duplicate rows

Tags: sql, database, plsql, oracle10g

I have a table contains order information like below:

```
[OrderTable]
```

As we can see from that table, each order_no has several duplicates. So what I want is to keep only one row for each order_no (no matter which )

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Distinct statement :

```
SELECT DISTINCT order_no
FROM OrderTable
[WHERE conditions];
```

Comment: I tried 'distinct', but some columns of those duplicate rows are different, so 'distinct' cannot solve the problem here. Is there any other way we can use? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
select distinct(order_no) from OrderTable
```

Comment: I tried 'distinct', but some columns of those duplicate rows are different, so 'distinct' cannot solve the problem here. Is there any other way we can use? Thanks.